TradingView stop orders not executing at correct price
I have a TradingView strategy, which opens orders at a stop price.
This is the code I use to open positions:
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=LongEntryPrice, alert_message = alert_string_open)
On backtest everything works correctly, trades are opened exactly at the stop levels, so they are opened intrabar (not at the bar open or close of next candle).
However, during the live data, the strategy is behaving differently, and trades are opened with significant delay/slippage. It seems that trades are open at the close of the next bar. However, if I refresh the page all the entry points become correct (intrabar and at the correct levels).
I am looking for a way to execute trades intrabar exactly at the stop price, during live data feed. I understand there could be some slippage in real-live trading, but I want to make TradingView trigger alerts without delays when the price reaches a certain level.
Any ideas what could be the possible reason for this?
What I have already tried to do:

calc_on_every_tick=true
I Tried removing all drawings, as I had a hypothesis that it is too heavy and recalculation takes a lot of time. The script now updates faster. But this didn't solve the issue.
Originally the strategy worked on range charts, I tried backtesting on traditional candlesticks, and the same issue.
Checked slippage in settings, it was zero

Update:
I have found the issue. It seems that stop orders execution in TradingView depends on the recalculation speed. As I wrote before, I use calculation on every tick
calc_on_every_tick=true  

I have added a few lines of code to plot a label with some data including the last order price and the current symbol price:
var label lb = na
label.delete(lb)
entry_price= strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
lb := label.new(bar_index, math.max(high, ta.highest(5)[1]), color=posCol, text="Pos: "+ posDir + "\nPnL:" + str.tostring(posProfit, "#.##")+"%" + "\nClose: "+str.tostring(close, "#.##")+str.tostring(posProfit, "#.##")+"%" + "\nOrder_price:"+str.tostring(order_price, "#.##"))

After this, I noticed that the 'close' price doesn't update on the label on every tick. Basically, I have compared how often price on the label updates versus the price on the price scale.
So for testing purposes, I created a very simple strategy, which opened a stop order slightly above the current price and plots the same label as above. I noticed, that with the simple script, the label is updated much more often, and stop orders work just fine.
My conclusion was that my script is too heavy and it takes significant time to recalculate, which caused the slippage.
I started to remove all pieces of code, that are not important: removed all drawings etc., and removed all functionality that was not used in the latest version of the code. Indeed that improved the stop order execution.
The strategy is designed to work on range charts, but can also be used with candlesticks. However, my goal is to automate live trading based on the range charts. So what I noticed with range charts, is that they are much more slower. I can get viable delay on candlesticks,  but when I switch to range charts, it takes a lot of time to recalculate.
This is quite clear to me why range charts are slower. With candlestics, TradingView just uses OHLC data to plot charts. With range charts it needs to calculate all bars.
So my question now is, is it possible to somehow limit the number of range bars in TradingView? I can guess TradingView is calculating the script based on 10000/20000 bars. I might need only the last 100 bars for my trading. I did some research and couldn't find the solution.
From my point of view, such implementation of stop orders by TradingView is incorrect. They need to be triggered independently from script recalculation.

This sounds like a repainting issue. Need to see your code (a minimal example at least).

I have updated my post. I found out that the issue is in the script recalculation speed.

you're right about too heavy script that takes significant time to recalculate. When script is too heavy it may skip the price updates. The only way rn is to optimise your code in runtime, try pine profiler (https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/boost-scripts-with-pine-profiler-44449/)
